# " It was a pleasure knowing", "It was a pleasure to have known", or "It was a pleasure to know"?

Tags: verbs, idioms, tenses

I am in the process of ordering a headstone for my dad and I wish to have the words

> It was a pleasure to have known

(as opposed to the more traditional "in loving remembrance", "in memory of", etc.) above his name. I am not sure which phrase is most grammatically correct. A headstone is not a place to make a mistake. Would

> - It was a pleasure knowing
> - It was a pleasure to have known
> - It was a pleasure to know

be correct?  Or is something else correct?

Comment: @mplungjan As this was meant to be atop the name, the question is rather; if "It was a pleasure knowing John Doe." is better than "It was a pleasure to have known John Doe." or "It was a pleasure to know John Doe."

Comment: I assumed this but it was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

They're all correct, although to my ear 'It was a pleasure to have known' sounds the most refined.

As a personal note, however, while I certainly appreciate the earnest sentiment in your saying that a 'headstone is not a place to make a mistake', I'd strongly urge you to select whichever phrase sounds best to **you.** Grammar and convention be damned, a headstone is a place to encapsulate a real, human relationship.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response.  I agree that 'It was a pleasure to have known' sounds the most refined.  Unless brevity is required, that's what I'll go with.  Thank you for the advice, too.  Not much about a person can be included on a headstone but my dad was such a nice guy, I wanted to indicate that.  Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I favor dropping the *it*. Some other suggestions:

> I was pleased to have known you.
>
> Knowing you was to have loved you.
>
> I was pleased to have known you.
>
> In knowing you, I felt great pleasure.
>
> I felt great pleasure in knowing you.
>
> I treasure having known you.
>
> To me and to many others, having known you was a great pleasure (or honor, or privilege).
>
> Having known you, I loved you.
>
> The pleasure of knowing you was all mine.